# Wave equation with angular variable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, coordinate-systems, wave-equation

Suppose that the variable of a mono-dimensional wave equation is an angle:

$$\frac{\partial^2 f(\phi)}{\partial \phi^2} + k_{\phi}^2 f(\phi) = 0$$

This equation is derived from a more complex (and separable) equation in cylindrical coordinates and $\phi$ is one of these coordinates. According to the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system#Definition), $0 \leq \phi < 2\pi$.

If I choose a cosinusoidal solution for $f(\phi)$, $k_{\phi}$ must be an integer.

$$\cos (\omega t - k_{\phi}\phi), k_{\phi} \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Why? Let the time $t$ be fixed and $0$. I know that the $f(\phi)$ must have for $\phi \to 2 \pi^-$ the same behaviour as for $\phi \to 0^+$, so that the function appears to be "continuous" in that point. This is possible only when the period of the function is a submultiple of $2\pi$, so $k_{\phi} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

But which could be a rigorous motivation for this?

Should the function be continuous across $\phi = 2\pi$? But this point doesn't even belong to the interval $[0,2\pi)$!

Comment: In cylindrical coordinates, the angle does not belong to an interval $[0,2\pi)$ but to the unit circle $\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$. Cylindrical functions must satisfy $f(0)=f(2\pi)$ because from the topology $2\pi=0$.

Comment: The way you state the question is a bit ambiguous. Do you mean: "If $f(\phi)=cos(\omega t - k_\phi \phi)$, then $k_\phi$ has to be an integer"?

Comment: I think you need to state boundary conditions. Why not just asking for $f(0)=f(2\pi)$? As you stated the problem, any $k\in\mathbb R$ would work.

Comment: @tomglabst No, I meant: "if $f(\phi) = \cos (\omega t - k_{\phi} \phi)$ **and** $f(\phi)$ represents the angular variation in cylindrical coordinates, why has necessarily $k_{\phi}$ to be an integer?". In other words, according to your second comment, why the cylindrical coordinates need the boundary conditions $f(0) = f(2 \pi)$? This was my actual question.

Answer (score 1):

I give a proof for the statement in my comment. As $k_\phi$ does not depend on $\phi$, I set $k:=k_\phi$.

Assume $t=0$, $k=\mathbb R$ and $f(\phi)=\cos(k \phi)$. Then $$f''(\phi)=-k^2\cos(k\phi)=-k^2f(\phi).$$ Therefore, $f$ is a solution to the Helmholtz equation in $(0,2\pi)$.

Now ask in addition for $f(0)=f(2\pi)$. Then, as you argued already in the question, $f(0)=1=f(2\pi)=\cos(k 2\pi)$. This is fulfilled exactly for $k\in\mathbb Z$.